# How to create a spoiler effect in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

How to create a spoiler effect in java swing like in HTML+JS.
For example, there are a few buttons "show" and when you click on one of them, showing under it image or text:
[image]
[image]
[image]

What method can be implemented like this?
I assume this can be implemented using JTree but will must drawing own components.

Comment: Unfortunately Stackoverflow is not the kind of site that codes stuff for you. You should show what effort you made to accomplish this and tell us where you got stuck instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `MySpoiler.setVisible(true)` within the "show" button callback.

If you want this to toggle between visible and non-visible, you will have to change the listener after each click to reverse the visibility of the image. The image itself can be placed within a swing `JLabel`.